# Facebook fb:fan - limit the number of posts it shows

Tags: facebook

I have incorporated the fb:fan control onto my web page.  The problem I have now, is I only want to show the latest post from the wall.  Currently it shows me all of them.  Is there a simple way to restrict this to the last comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  But, you can set the CSS overflow to hidden.

Comment: Thanks.  It's a shame that you don't get more control over it.